# iOS select image from camera roll Cordova

Tags: html, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a jqm+phonegap application running on cordova 2.9.0 for ios platform.

On android, the following code worked, but isn't working on iOS...

JS:

```
function getImage() {

navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
alert('Get Picture Failed. Please Try Again.');
},{
quality: 50,
destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
}
);

}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=curClub+imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

var params = new Object();
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";
params.clubID = curClub ;
options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, "url", win, fail, options);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role = "button" onClick = "getImage();" >Upload Logo</div>
```

If i test the getImage() function by adding an alert inside, it works, so i know that it is going there. What else am I doing wrong?

Do I need to add any permissions in config.xml?

Or what different code is required to make it work on ios?

Comment: Have you added <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" /> in it?

Comment: it was already in the config.xml file, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you give permission when you first calling that function?
ios would ask permission to access camera roll at the first time

Comment: yes, it works now, i just closed xcode and reopened it and re-ran the program